# what does "express.js is minimal framework" mean?

Tags: node.js, express

i read in express doc that "Express is a minimal and flexible Node.js web application framework", but what does the term **"minimal"** or "**minimalist"** mean in context of coding?

Ref:
[https://expressjs.com/#:~:text=Express%20is%20a%20minimal%20and,for%20web%20and%20mobile%20applications](https://expressjs.com/#:%7E:text=Express%20is%20a%20minimal%20and,for%20web%20and%20mobile%20applications)

Comment: I think it means that it doesn't aim to provide solutions to every aspect of an application.  It's essentially focussed on providing routing middleware for requests and their responses.  If you look at the API, it consists of Application, Request, Response and Router -- that's it.  That's pretty minimal.  But it's quite robust and flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express is considered as a minimal framework because it is very convenient and flexible for small project.

You don't have a rigid structure as with Laravel for instance.

You can do pretty much everything you want in Express,
If you don't want to respect a clear structure of routes, middlewares, controllers you can.

If you want to create the whole API in the same file you can to !

Moreover it's a very light framework if you compare it to huge stuff like Laravel (again ^^).

But does come at a cost, you need to install lot of stuffs on your own, like jwt for Authentication support or Nodemailer for mail handling.